# How to insert values one by one to a pandas DataFrame while checking which topic they belong to?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, insert

I have a set of general topics which are the headers of my dataframe - e.g.  `[General Pharmacology, Toxicology and Pharmaceutics, General Medicine, General Biochemistry, Genetics and Molecular Biology, General Chemical Engineering, General Dentistry,Others]`. And I have a list of subtopics like

```
['Spectroscopy',
 'Maternity and Midwifery',
 'Emergency',
 'Management Science and Operations Research',
 'Economics and Econometrics',
 'Transplantation',
 'Discrete Mathematics and Combinatorics',
 'Communication',
 'Colloid and Surface Chemistry',
 'Psychology (miscellaneous)',
 'Health, Toxicology and Mutagenesis',
 'Medical–Surgical',
 'Urban Studies',
 'Geophysics',
 'Geology',
 'Neuropsychology and Physiological Psychology',
 'Space and Planetary Science',
 'Chemistry (miscellaneous)',
 'Marketing',
 'Inorganic Chemistry',
 'Experimental and Cognitive Psychology',
 'Condensed Matter Physics',
 'Architecture ',
 'Chemical Health and Safety',
 'Biological Psychiatry',
 'Dermatology',
 'Medicine (miscellaneous)',
 'Biochemistry, Genetics and Molecular Biology (miscellaneous)',
 'Speech and Hearing',
 'Anesthesiology and Pain Medicine',
 'Reproductive Medicine',
 'Small Animals',
 'Religious studies',
 'Insect Science',
 'Ceramics and Composites',
 'Multidisciplinary',
 'Health Policy',
 'Atmospheric Science',
 'Physiology']
```

which I would like to inspect before inserting it into the correct column.

Is there a way of looping over the subtopics while choosing the column to insert the values?

Comment: I'm assuming there's some sort of logic that maps the subtopics to the general topics?  If so, why don't you encode that information in a dictionary?  e.g. `{'Spectroscopy': 'Genetics and Molecular Biology', ...}`.  Then you could use the pandas `.map` method, then one-hot encode to get your general category columns

Comment: @Jed, Thanks for the answer. That's what I'm doing, but as they are so many subtopics I'm getting confused. That's why I'm looking for an alternative. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878375/how-to-create-tree-structure-from-hierarchical-data-in-python